# Call a URL whithin a flow

Tags: apex, flow-screen-component

I'm pretty new in the concept of flows in SF. I have a button attached to an object which you can see its configurations below; after clicking on the button, this URL will be called:

[image]

Now I was asked to create a flow that does the same thing as what this button does. Actually I need this URL to be called **automatically** under some conditions that I define in the flow.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I did a lot of research but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: check out this: https://unofficialsf.com/navigate-everywhere-flow-action/

Answer (score -1):

You to need to follow the given steps by carefully setting/assigning the fields/values/conditions as required :

Step 1: Create an external credential by specifying the Authentication Protocol. After saving this credential, create a new Principal record that needs to be assigned to a Permission set.

Step 2: Create a named credential by specifying the correct URL.

Step 3: Create a permission set for making HTTP callouts by assigning 'External Credential Principal Access'.

Step 4: Assign this permission set to the required users.

Step 5: Create a new screen flow by adding components and elements as needed.

Step 6: Create an Action by adding a 'Create HTTP Callout' action element. Provide the external service name, select the named credential created above, and click 'Next.' Configure the invocable action by providing a Label, Method, the path to be appended to the URL set in the named credential, and set parameter keys to be passed (Master ID and Template ID in your case). Also, provide the correct 'Sample response' and finally click 'Save'.

Step 7: Once the HTTP Callout action is created, provide a name to the Action element and populate the parameters to be passed. Then, click 'Done'.

Step 8: Add a Decision element to check conditionally generate responses for 'Success' and 'Failure' scenarios based upon HTTP callout performed.Add screen elements for them individually.

Step 9: Save the flow and then debug by providing the required details.

Step 10: Activate the flow.